# Kubernetes pod marked as `Completed` despite the exit code `255`

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

**Situation:**
I've got a CronJob that often fails (this is expected at the moment). Due to the fact that the container performing the job, has a side-car, the dependencies are between the containers are expressed through bash scripts and common mounts of `emptyDir` in `/etc/liveness` folder:

```
        spec:
          containers:
          - args:
            - -c
            - set -x;
              ...
              ./process; # execute the main process
              rc=$?;
              rm /etc/liveness; # clean-up
              exit $rc;
            command:
            - /bin/bash
```

**Problem:**
In the scenarios, where the job fails, I see the following in the logs:

```
+ rc=255
+ rm /etc/liveness
+ exit 255
```

With `retryPolicy` set to `never`, the failed pod enters the `Completed` status, which is misleading:

```
scheduler-1594015200-wl9xc   0/2     Completed     0          24m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A Pod's status field is a PodStatus object, which has a phase field.

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase

Status and Phase is not the same. So I learned, that what happens above is that my pods end up in status `Completed` and phase `Failed`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/),

> A Job creates one or more Pods and ensures that a specified number of
> them successfully **terminate**.

And containers enter [**terminated state**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-states) when

> it has successfully completed execution or when it has failed for some
> reason.

So if you set retryPolicy to never, this is what will happen.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't get your answer. So why is the pod status `Completed` and not `Failed`?

Comment: The Pod is Failed. The job is Completed.

Comment: Hi @coderanger  as you can see in my question in the output of the `kubectl get pods` command, the **pod** is not `Failed`, it's `Completed`.

Besides, from the docs: Description: Failed. All Containers in the Pod have terminated, and at least one Container has terminated in failure. That is, the Container either exited with non-zero status or was terminated by the system.

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase